# Running a Custom Build on Jenkins using Web Service API

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins provide a Custom Build option for mavenized projects, where we can specify different Maven goals to run as a build.

[image]

Does anyone know how to trigger a custom build like above using Jenkins Web Service API?

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a build parameter, say `goal_param`. You set it's default value to `sonar:sonar`. Then inside *Maven Goals* you specify `${goal_param}`. Then you can start your job in a 'usual' fashion: `http://[jenkins_server]/[job_name]/buildWithParameters?goal_param=[value]`.